# .Net Core: controlling Json generated by Controller.Json method

Tags: json, asp.net-core

By default, Controller.Json generates JSON for each public member of a class. How can I change this so that some members are ignored. Please note that I am using .Net Core.

Example:

```
[HttpGet("/api/episodes")]
public IActionResult GetEpisodes()
{
  var episodes = _podcastProvider.Get();

  return Json(episodes);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't do that for two reasons: a) it tightly couples your API to the Database models (each change to it breaks your API) and b) it tightly couples your viewmodels to JSON.NET. You should always use own models for returning API values (i.e. viewmodels, binding models, DataTransferObjects)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute that available in `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace like below:

```
public class Model
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [JsonIgnore]
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I change this so that some members are ignored?

Under the covers this uses [`Newtonsoft.Json`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). There are two ways you can do this.

1. Use the `JsonIgnore` attribute and mark the properties you want omitted.
2. Have your `episodes` class define itself as "opt-in", meaning only properties marked with `JsonProperty` are serialized. `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`

It depends on the number of properties you need omitted versus serialized.

```
public class Episode 
{
    public int Id { get; }
    [JsonIgnore] public string Name { get; }
    [JsonIgnore] public Uri Uri { get; }
    [JsonIgnore] public long Length { get; }
}
```

The above will yield the same JSON as this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Episode 
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Uri Uri { get; }
    public long Length { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise Newtonsoft.Json was included in .Net core.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, it is noteworthy to mention that there is a actually an overload too for the `Json` method, that takes the `SerializationSettings` instance. Which allows for even more control.