# Json Ignore properties during runtime

Tags: c#, json, rest, security, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Web Service that returns object based on requests received from the client. Lets say based on the user rights, I would like hide some property values from the client. 
I have a solution: I can clone the object that needs to be sent, but exclude the properties that are needed during the clone and send. So far this is the best solution I have found, but I am wondering if there are any other ways where i can specify the list of properties to a Json serializer so that it does it for me automatically.

Comment: Do you want to make it in client while the web api response has the all data?Or you want to change the web api response to contain specific properties?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a user rights consideration, then you should not rely on the way data is serialized (here, JSON). What happens the day you change your serialization process or send something else than a JSON? You will end up sending inappropriate data.

A better option in my opinion would be to first create a CLR object according to your user rights (for example by copying only the needed properties into another class), and then worry about serializing it into JSON, regardless of user rights.

So basically, shift the filtering of data from JSON to CLR.

Comment: That is my solution so far, but was wondering if there are other ways of doing it without bothering the new instance.

Comment: Actually it's a type of ViewModel based on user rights. You could populate the object using JsonConvert.Populate(text,object) those properties that exist will get set, those that do not exist will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Yo could just use [JsonIgnore] on the properties which you do not want to be serialized.

```
public class Engine
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int engineNo { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string engineHost { get; set; }
}
```

And when you return json result, it will ignore those properties automitically:

```
public JsonResult GetEngineers()
    {            
        var engines= _context.Engines.ToList() ; 
        return Json(engines);
    }
```

Result:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]
```

Refer to [.Net Core: controlling Json generated by Controller.Json method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975644/net-core-controlling-json-generated-by-controller-json-method)

Besides,The IContractResolver interface provides a way to customize how the JsonSerializer serializes and deserializes .NET objects to JSON without placing attributes on your classes.

Refer to https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use ShouldSerialize Method to ignore property dynamically, Let say u have a property with name FirstName then u can create a method given below

```
    public bool ShouldSerializeFirstName()
    {
        return false; // this could be a conditional statement
    }
```